# How to format password using SCP

Tags: password, character-encoding

I'm currently writing a Script to upload files to my server via SCP.

I have the following line:

```
sshpass -p password!% scp -P 1234 ./test.text user@mydyndns:~/test.txt
```

But everytime I try that I get stuck at authenticating. I can see that this is probably because of the password. It has as well as in the example a '!' and a '%' in it. Everytime I press enter I see that the command was send without the two special characters. I tried replacing them with percet-enconding, but to no success (%25, %21).

Any ideas?

Comment: I also tried to escape the characters with \! and \%. no sucess either!

Comment: Okay, I'm retarded. I missspelled my user name (capital letter...) and it then worked with escpaing the characters.

Answer (score 0):

try

1) single quoting,

```
sshpass -p 'password!%' scp -P 1234 ./test.text user@mydyndns:~/test.txt
```

2) use other sshpass method

- file : `sshpass -f passwd.txt ...`

  where passwd.txt contains **passwd!%**
- environnement var `sshpass -e ...`

  where SSHPASS contains your password.

3) I assume there is a good reason for not using public/private  key.

Comment: Thanks, commented how I fixed it. The only good reason I don't use keys yet is that I want to go simple for now. But its defintely on my list as I know it's the more secure way!

Comment: @Fabian: hmm, odd ... for me keys are a lot simpler and certainly more convenient.

Comment: @Fabian, try `ssh-copyid user@mydyndns` you have to give password once. key pair is set.